# why does my phonegap build app not work for Android tablets?

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, phonegap-build

I build a Mobile app using HTML5, Javascript and CSS3 using the PhoneGap API. I used the Phonegap Build to generate my .apk release file. I was expecting my apk to run on phones as well as tablets since i was using jquery mobile. However when i submit my app to google play store i get the following message

> Design your app for tablets
>
> Your Production APK needs to meet the following criteria:
>
> The minimum Android version and target Android version need to support
>   tablets (check targetSdkVersion and minSdkVersion)

I was expecting the phone gap build to do that ?

UPDATE:

I also added the below tags to my index.html page but it would still display the same message help ?

```
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
  <preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="19" />
  <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="19" />
```

Comment: check this doc link http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/2.9.0/configuring_preferences.md.html

Comment: @StackOverflowUser thanks for the link. So do i add the <preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="15" /> in index.html file only? or should i add it in all the html files kind of confused here ?

Comment: yes you need specific app version minimum android sdk version and max android sdk version :)

Comment: @StackOverflowUser i added   <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="19" />  this to my index.html file in the <head> but it would still display the same message. check my update ?

Comment: why you mention in two times in your xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making mistake on your android manifest:

1. Your android min version is set to 7, but Initial support for tablets was added in Android 3.0 (API level 11). So it must be 11 or higher.
2. Under uses-feature and uses-permission, you're requiring some hardware features that maybe not available on some tablet like front camera or telephony. For all this kind of features,  you should add a new parameter `android:required="false"`

Here is the soure with more details from android developper website.

http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/tablet.html#android-versions
http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/tablet.html#hardware-requirements

Comment: i am using build.phonegap to build my app in which case phonegap builds the app for me. I am trying to understand were do i enter android:required="false" ? is it in the index.html file ? if i do that since it builds for iOS as well will that conflict ?

Comment: <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />

Comment: Yah I get to know that you are using Phonegap build. Like above add in your config.xml

Answer (score 1):

I also get the message in Google Play Developer under "Optimization Tips":
"**Design your app for tablets...Show details... The minimum Android version and target Android version need to support tablets (check targetSdkVersion and minSdkVersion).**"

So I added to the PhoneGap Build config.xml file:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="11" /> 
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="14" />
```

because that is what is recommended at http://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/tablets.html#android-versions

Uploaded the new apk to the Google Play store and it says that the new version supports 1200 less devices and I still get the same message about "**The minimum Android version and target Android version need to support tablets (check targetSdkVersion and minSdkVersion).**"

It seems the app is better off without adding the version lines to config.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I also get the message in Google Play Developer under "Optimization Tips":
"**Design your app for tablets...Show details... The minimum Android version and target Android version need to support tablets (check targetSdkVersion and minSdkVersion).**"

So I added to the PhoneGap Build config.xml file:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="11" /> 
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="14" />
```

because that is what is recommended at http://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/tablets.html#android-versions

Uploaded the new apk to the Google Play store and it says that the new version supports 1200 less devices and I still get the same message about "**The minimum Android version and target Android version need to support tablets (check targetSdkVersion and minSdkVersion).**"

It seems the app is better off without adding the version lines to config.xml.

**Update**

There is a comment at http://unitycoder.com/blog/2014/03/18/your-apk-does-not-seem-to-be-designed-for-tablets/ that indicates that if you upload screenshots for tablets and there is too much whitespace in the screenshot then that is probably the reason for Google's message about your app not being optimized for tablets.